# Wrong behaviour with float and nested empty div

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

i have this: http://jsfiddle.net/uAQ8B/5/

This list should have all the objects on the left and every parent on the right. It works fine unless the parent is empty, like in this case where object 1 has a parent but object2-5 don't.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Pavan, you need to clear your left floats, otherwise the elements will just line up.

You can do this by adding `clear: both` (or just `clear: left` since you are only floating elements `left`) to your `.Discussioni` class:

```
.Discussioni {
    clear: both;
}
```

See this CSS tricks article about using floats: [All About Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)